# Rich html CiviMails can send from a Mac but not Windows?

Tags: civimail, email

I've an issue with the new 4.6.5 CiviMail on Joomla 3.4.3 where the 'send test' button remains deactivated after pasting in content - and when a draft is saved, it saves blank.

We send out a weekly newsletter that is rendered as a web page ( http://www.pctscotland.co.uk/latest-newsletter ), the source html of this is copied and pasted into the source of the CiviMail interface. This has been working for some years but stopped after I upgraded to 4.6.3 (normal composed mass mails were fine but not these html ones copied and pasted). Upgrading to 4.6.5 fixed this for me (Mac Chrome/Firefox) - but not for the other site users using Windows Chrome.

They paste the content in, fill in the required fields and the 'send test' button remains greyed, with no 'preview as html' link to the left. When they save the draft, it saves it as blank. When I do the same, it works. I've just done a detailed screen share to make sure there is no difference in processes - and there isn't. All users trying to do this have the same super user privileges.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Nic

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard any other issues like this so I suspect this has been solved by now. Please upgrade to the latest version and try again.